# Looping through DetailsView to hide dynamic BulletedList items

Tags: vb.net, detailsview, bulletedlist

I need to be able to hide 2 options that are displayed from my dynamic bulletedlist (which is built inside of a DetailsView). Every time I try writing a loop through the BulletedList, I get an error saying that it is not a collection type, so I thought I could loop through the DetailsView to find the items I want to hide.

I can't change the SQL because this particular bulleted list gets used on 2 different pages, it's just that on one, I only need to show 2 of the 4 items that are associated with the ID.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Answer(s)" SortExpression="PicklistID">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenPicklistID" runat="server"  
            Value='<%# Bind("PicklistID") %>' />
            <asp:BulletedList ID="blText" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsPicklist" 
            DataTextField="TEXT">
            </asp:BulletedList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPicklist" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SurveyConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT p.TEXT FROM PICKLIST p 
                       JOIN C_Survey_Questions c 
                       ON p.PICKLISTID = c.PicklistID 
                       AND c.QuestionID = @QuestionID 
                       AND c.SurveyID = @SurveyID 
                       WHERE p.PICKLISTID IS NOT NULL 
                       AND c.PicklistID IS NOT NULL">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="SurveyID" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hiddenQuestionID" Name="QuestionID" 
                PropertyName="Value" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I've tried:

```
    Protected Sub blText_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim blText As BulletedList
    For Each BulletedListItem In blText

    Next
End Sub
```

but Visual Studio tells me that it is not a collection type. So I thought I could just put a For Each in the code below. I don't know how to loop through the DetailsView though, can someone point me in the right direction here?

```
Protected Sub dvSurveyQuestions_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
System.EventArgs) Handles dvSurveyQuestions.DataBound
End Sub
```

UPDATE 2/6: I declared my BulletedList by using a FindControl and there were no more errors saying the BulletedList wasn't declared.

```
Protected Sub blText_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim blText As BulletedList = dvSurveyQuestions.FindControl("blText")
    For Each i As ListItem In blText.Items

    Next
End Sub
```

ANOTHER UPDATE: I need to get the blText for the unique QuestionID of 33. The QuestionID is an Integer, but I don't know how to associate a HiddenField with an Integer field. In this code, "Is" gets underlined saying that`Is operator does not accept opeands of type 'Integer.'` So I change the Is to an = and get the error `Operator = is not defined for types HiddenField and Integer.`

```
Dim QuestionID = DirectCast(dvSurveyQuestions.FindControl("hiddenQuestionID"), HiddenField)
    If QuestionID Is 33 Then
        Dim blText As BulletedList = dvSurveyQuestions.FindControl("blText")
        For intCursor = (blText.Items.Count - 1) To 0 Step -1
            If blText.Items(intCursor).Text = "Self Directed" Or "Systems" Then
                blText.Items.RemoveAt(intCursor)
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

**This is what works**

```
 Dim QuestionID As Integer = CInt(CType(dvSurveyQuestions.FindControl("hiddenQuestionID"), HiddenField).Value)
    If QuestionID = 33 Then
        Dim blText As BulletedList = dvSurveyQuestions.FindControl("blText")
        For intCursor = (blText.Items.Count - 1) To 0 Step -1
            If blText.Items(intCursor).Text = "Self Directed" Or blText.Items(intCursor).Text = "Systems" Then
                blText.Items.RemoveAt(intCursor)
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: You're looking for the HiddenField's Value property, which can be inferred, but here it is with the casting... Dim QuestionID As Integer = CInt(CType(dvSurveyQuestions.FindControl("hiddenQuestionID"), HiddenField).Value) 'If QuestionID = 33 Then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop from the Items property of the BulletList.

```
    For Each i As ListItem In blText.Items

    Next
```

This is probably more specific to your problem...

```
    For intCursor = (blText.Items.Count - 1) To 0 Step -1

        If blText.Items(intCursor).Text = "TextValueToRemove" Then

            blText.Items.RemoveAt(intCursor)

        End If

    Next
```

Comment: Do you know how I can declare the bulleted list in the codebehind? I just get squiggly lines with everything I do saying that it's not a member of bulleted list. I have `Dim blText As BulletedList = blText.Items` and I've tried blText.BulletedList, blText.List, but those give me a squiggly lines too.

Comment: Visual Studio should be wiring it up for you since you added the runat="Server" on the Aspx page.  When you remove the Dim bltText As BulletList line of code do you get errors that say blText is undefined?

Comment: As a follow up, if it does say blText is undefined after removing the Dim blText statement, check the very top of your aspx page and make sure that CodeBehind="PageName.aspx.vb" and Inherits="Full.Class.Name".  And when all else fails, you can try to Clean and Rebuild a couple times too.

Comment: It does say that it is undefined if I delete the `Dim blText As BulletedList` and the top of my page vb page says `Partial Class Admin_ManageQuestions
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page` so do I need to try Clean and Rebuild? I've never done that before.

Comment: On your ASPX page (not the .vb file), at the top in your page declarations, make sure that your CodeBehind="Admin_ManageQuestions.aspx.vb", Inherits="YourProjectsNameSpace.Admin_ManageQuestions", and then clean and rebuild.  That way the controls you define in your ASPX page get declared WithEvents (usually done in a designer file, ex = YourProjectsNameSpace.Admin_ManageQuestions.aspx.designer.vb) and become available in the code behind.

Comment: I changed the `CodeFile="ManageQuestions.aspx.vb"` to `CodeFile="Admin_ManageQuestions.aspx.vb"` and then clicked on Rebuild and have all kinds of errors saying that Admin_ManageQuestions.aspx.vb was not found. I'm not sure where to find Clean and Rebuild. The only options in the Build dropdown are Build, Rebuild, and Publish.

Comment: If your page name is ManageQuestions.aspx.vb you will want it to be that.  Check out these MSDN links.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/015103yb.aspx / http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx - Once your codebehind is hooked into your .aspx page properly, the answer I provided should help you remove the items you wish to filter by.

Comment: I put the code in that you provided and there are no errors. However, I thought of something that I didn't think of before. This bulleted list is connected to a unique QuestionID, which is a HiddenField. I had to use the code I put in my latest edit, but the HiddenField can't use Integers? I feel like I should know how to do this part....